# Better VB.NET String Scrambler?

Tags: vb.net, string, scramble

I needed a function to take a string phrase and scramble it.  So I wrote this, but I'm wondering if there is a more efficient/faster way to do it?

```
    Public Function Scramble(phrase As String) As String
    Dim rand As New Random()
    Dim newPhrase As String = ""
    Dim clist As New List(Of String)

    ' break phrase into characters and add to list
    For i As Integer = 1 To Len(phrase)
        clist.Add(Mid(phrase.ToLower(), i, 1))
    Next

    ' remove from list randomly and add to new string
    Do While clist.Count > 0
        Dim r As Integer = rand.Next(0, clist.Count)
        newPhrase &= clist(r)
        clist.RemoveAt(r)
    Loop

    Return newPhrase

End Function
```

Comment: `New String(theStr.ToCharArray.OrderBy(Function(r) rnd.Next).ToArray)`  not sure if it is better, but it is shorter. You could also use the Fisher-Yates shuffle on the Char Array.  If this is for anything but some sort of guessing game, you are better of using actual encryption.

Comment: You should also change the declaration of `rand` from `Dim` to `Static` so you only have one instance that gets re-used over and over.  Without it, you'd get the same "random" scramble on very fast successive calls.

Comment: `more efficient/faster way to do it?`  If this is your goal, you need to measure it.  What is an acceptable speed?

Comment: Not looking for encryption in a security sense. This is for a Roguelike. This function gets used if a new world/game is generated. Certain item names (such as scrolls) are scrambled up until properly identified.

Performance isn't a huge factor, but I try to be efficient whenever possible, hence the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's Plutonix's one-liner:

```
Public Function Scramble(ByVal phrase As String) As String
    Static rand As New Random()
    Return New String(phrase.ToLower.ToCharArray.OrderBy(Function(r) rand.Next).ToArray)
End Function
```

...and here's an alternate version of your longer form:

```
Public Function Scramble(ByVal phrase As String) As String
    Static rand As New Random()
    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder
    Dim chars As New List(Of Char)(phrase.ToLower.ToCharArray)
    While chars.Count > 0
        Dim r As Integer = rand.Next(0, chars.Count)
        sb.Append(chars(r))
        chars.RemoveAt(r)
    End While
    Return sb.ToString
End Function
```